# Ruby methods confusion

Tags: ruby, methods

If I run:

```
myObj.methods - Object.methods
```

I see the method I expect listed in the results:

```
[:myMethod]
```

If I then run:

```
myObj.myMethod()
```

I get the following error:

```
symbol lookup error ... undefined symbol: myMethod
```

What is happening? Am I calling `myMethod` correctly?

Comment: We need to see the definition of the class of which `myObj` is an instance, including the definition of the instance method `myMethod`. Aside: one of Ruby's conventions is to use "snake-case" for names of variables and methods. For example, `my_method` instead of `myMethod`. You don't have to follow this convention, but 99%+ of Rubiests do.

Comment: "symbol lookup error" usually happens when using a gem with native code that was compiled for a different version of Ruby than the one you're using, or when using an incompatible version of Ruby. It doesn't have anything to do with your method being defined or undefined. We can't help you diagnose any further, however, without seeing your actual code and the complete error message including the stack trace.

Comment: By the way. `Object.methods` will return an array of *class* methods; you may have been expecting *instance* methods.  You can call get public instance methods by calling `Object.instance_methods` or `Object.public_instance_methods`, and private instance methods by calling `Object.private_instance_methods`.

Comment: What if you run `myObj.myMethod`.

Comment: In this example, myObj is defined in a custom gem that was created using SWIG.